# calculate market weighted return using SAS

Tags: sas

I have four variables `Name`, `Date`, `MarketCap` and `Return`. `Name` is the company name. `Date` is the time stamp. `MarketCap` shows the size of the company. `Return` is its return at day `Date`.

I want to create an additional variable `MarketReturn` which is the value weighted return of the market at each point time. For each day t, MarketCap weighted return = sum [ return(i)* (MarketCap(i)/Total(MarketCap) ] (return(i) is company i's return at day t).

The way I do this is very inefficient. I guess there must be some function can easily achieve this traget in SAS, So I want to ask if anyone can improve my code please.

step1: sort data by `date`
step2: calculate total market value at each day  `TotalMV` = sum(MarketCap).
step3: calculate the weight for each company  (weight = `MarketCap`/`TotalMV`)
step4: create a new variable 'Contribution' = Return * weight for each company 
step5: sum up `Contribution` at each day. Sum(Contribution)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Weighted averages are supported in a number of SAS PROCs. One of the more common, all-around useful ones is `PROC SUMMARY`:

```
PROC SUMMARY NWAY DATA = my_data_set ; 
    CLASS Date ; 

    VAR Return / WEIGHT = MarketCap ;

    OUTPUT
       OUT = my_result_set 
       MEAN (Return) = MarketReturn
    ;
RUN;
```

The `NWAY` piece tells the PROC that the observations should be grouped only by what is stated in the `CLASS` statement - it shouldn't also provide an ungrouped grand total, etc.

The `CLASS Date` piece tells the PROC to group the observations by date. You do not need to pre-sort the data when you use `CLASS`. You do have to pre-sort if you say `BY Date` instead.  The only rationale for using `BY` is if your dataset is very large and naturally ordered, you can gain some performance.  Stick to `CLASS` in most cases.

`VAR Return / WEIGHT = MarketCap` tells the proc that any weighted calculations on `Return` should use `MarketCap` as the weight.

Lastly, the `OUTPUT` statement specifies the data set to write the results to (using the `OUT` option), and specifies the calculation of a mean on `Return` that will be written as `MarketReturn`.

There are many, many more things you can do with `PROC SUMMARY`.  The documentation for `PROC SUMMARY` is sparse, but only because it is the nearly identical sibling of `PROC MEANS`, and SAS did not want to produce reams of mostly identical documentation for both.  [Here is the link to the SAS 9.4 `PROC MEANS` documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/67327/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p0f0fjpjeuco4gn1ri963f683mi4.htm).  The main difference between the two PROCS is that `SUMMARY` only outputs to a dataset, while `MEANS` by default outputs to the screen.  Try `PROC MEANS` if you want to see the result pop up on the screen right away.

The `MEAN` keyword in the `OUTPUT` statement comes from SAS's list of statistical keywords, [a helpful reference for which is here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/67327/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p0v0y1on1hbxukn0zqgsp5ky8hc0.htm).